# Modifying rolled over log filename to include date in log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm using the following setting in log4j.properties. However, it generates a file like `MyLog.log.2010-11-26` during roll over. Is there a way I can make it `MyLog-2010-11-26.log`?

```
log4j.appender.fileLog=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileLog.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.fileLog.File=logs/MyLog.log
```

I can make `DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'` but it makes it `MyLog.log.2010-11-26.log`. Is there a way to modify File setting so I can insert the DatePattern?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using [`org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html) from the [apache-log4j-extras](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/index.html) package; that appears to be able to do the thing that you want if you configure it right. I *think* that the example configuration on that file is only trivially different from what you require.

Comment: I tried but can't make it to work yet. But at least it seems to be what I need.

Comment: @jasonline: I caution that I've never used it as I'm happy enough with the standard version's tradeoffs.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a custom appender which does this.